# Explanation std::aligned_storage and reinterpret cast

Tags: c++, c++11

Could you please look at this lines of [code taken from cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/aligned_storage/) and translate them for me, explaining them line by line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {  // non-POD type
  int avg;
  A (int a, int b) : avg((a+b)/2) {}
};

typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A),alignof(A)>::type A_pod;

int main() {
  A_pod a,b;
  new (&a) A (10,20);
  b=a;
  std::cout << reinterpret_cast<A&>(b).avg << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So this is my explanation.

- First of all this class is non - POD because a non-trivial constructor is defined ( a user-defined constructor is non-trivial, at least I think).
- this is starting to be a little more difficult to grasp: `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>type:: A_pod;` is used to get an uninitialised, aligned block of memory. We need to provide the sizeof the object we want to store and the alignment using alignof(A) ( for instance we would need an align == 4, for char == 1, for float == 4, for short == 2, and so on ...).
- With the line  `A_pod a, b;` we are getting uninitialised blocks of memory;
- `new (&a) A (10, 20);` Here placement new is used and only now we are actually constructing the object by providing the pointer to the block of memory just allocated.
- `b = a`  is probably the copy constructor and the content of block of memory a is going to be copied in block of memory b.
- This is the part that I do not understand probably also because I almost never seen nor needed to really use reinterpret_cast. So here reinterpret cast is not doing any bit computation but is simply telling the compiler to treat b as a reference of type A, right?. My question is why do we need to do that. Probably just to access the member average but would not be way of accessing it with a?
- Could someone also show some code using std::aligned_storage to understand it better, I looked up some other questions but just found probably three examples. I would also appreciate if you could give an explanation, and give a reason for the choice of aligned_storage.Thanks in advance.

P.S. could also someone tell me when to use an allocator to allocate uninitialised memory and when to use this approach?

Comment: I don't think this is a good example for understanding of `std::aligned_storage`. Maybe a better one would be an implementation of an `std::optional`-like class. Then, you need an internal buffer, where an object of some type will be later optionally initialized. `std::aligned_storage` is just a library helper for the definition a type for such a buffer. You can also use a properly sized and aligned array of type `unsigned char` or `std::byte` as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr `std::aligned_storage_t` probably is "a properly sized and aligned array of type `unsigned char`", see the [Possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage#Possible_implementation)

Comment: "Could someone also show some code using `std::aligned_storage` to understand it better" - I will raise you with a paper instead: [P1413R3: Deprecate std::aligned_storage and std::aligned_union](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1413r3.pdf).

Comment: "I almost never seen nor needed to really use reinterpret_cast? Great, you should try keeping it this way. "My question is why do we need to do that" Because we need a reference to A in order to call `A::avg`, but there is no other way to obtain a reference to A from a reference to aligned-storage-for-A.

Comment: @Caleth Note that it is actually a class (`struct`) that contains such an array. If it was just an array itself, we couldn't copy it (with`b=a` here). But yes, effectively they are the same.